# Communication between Custom Modules in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms-1.8, orchard-modules

I'm a newbie to Orchard CMS. My problem is that I have created a couple of custom modules on my Orchard site, but am so far unable to raise events and communicate between these modules.

From what I’ve read, the EventBus Pattern and IEventHandler is the best way to go about this, but am having difficulty implementing it, as so far I’ve been unable to find any substantial information in this area online.

If anyone know's of any comprehensive tutorials or can point me in the right direction on how best to go about this, I would really appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: What do you mean 'communicate'? You can just add a reference to another module's project. Then use dependency injection to inject the services you need.

Comment: Hi, thank's for replying....i am trying to create completely independent modules that I can plug into any future applications, so therefore didn't think adding references was the way to go (only new to this so not sure of best way)....I have been referencing this tutorial http://skywalkersoftwaredevelopment.net/orchard-development/api/ieventhandler, but am still having difficulty with it, so wondered if anybody knew of any tutorials that go through the process from start to finish, as I can't seem to find any. Thanks for any help with it.

Comment: Maybe you mean something like the PartHandlers? Checkout the Orchard.Comments module -> Handlers -> CommentPartHandler. It uses dependency injection to inject the needed services (can also be services of another module, that's when you need a project reference), and adds some events that will be handled by the injected service.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help, I'll have a look at that so.