# Is there a way to add custom event handlers to a part in Orchard?

Tags: orchardcms

Basically I have a module, that has a class, that has method where I will be receiving different types of content items as a parameter, as well as a string representing the **custom** event type. Depending on which type of content item is passed in I want to handle this item in a certain way by invoking its custom handler method for which ever type of event it is.

I am trying to avoid coupling at all costs so this module should not know of these content items or its event handling methods.

1. I need to return a list of all registered handlers or handler methods for whatever content item I am passing in.
2. Based on what kind of event this is, I then need to call the (registered?) event handler method for this content item.

Is there a way to do this in orchard???

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do: it would help if you could explain the scenario. It's very likely that there already is a standard way of achieving whatever you're trying, and that it may diverge from your idea of how it should work. For instance, Orchard has a standard event bus. Do you know about it, and have reasons not to use that?

Comment: I just came across this post on stackoverflow which is exactly what I'm trying to do and perhaps he explains it better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25848958/communication-between-custom-modules-in-orchard-cms. So yea it does seem like using the event bus and implementing an Ieventhandler is the way to achieve what I'm trying to do in order to avoid referencing other modules. But unfortunately this url: http://www.ideliverable.com/blog/ieventhandler seems to be the only tutorial I can find on the subject and I'm failing to wrap my head around the concept...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Communicating accross modules is not that hard once you get the hang of it. There are also several ways to achieve this.
This answer is based on your last comment, since Bertrand pointed you in the right direction.

**Using simple EventHandlers**

For a more sophisticated example, look at the existing *IUserEventHandler* in *Orchard.Users*.

*Module A*

*Services/IMyCustomEventHandler.cs*

```
namespace My.ModuleA.Services
{
    // This is the eventHandler you inject wherever you need it. (e.g. Module B)
    public interface IMyCustomEventHandler : IEventHandler
    {
        // IContent should suit you in this case but you could also pass in 
        // just the contentItem id, or whatever else you need.
        void SomethingHappened(IContent content);
    }
}
```

*Module B*

*Controllers/FancyController.cs*

```
namespace My.ModuleB.Controllers
{
    public class FancyController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IMyCustomEventHandler handler;

        public FancyController(IMyCustomEventHandler handler)
        {
            this.handler = handler;
        }

        public ActionResult DoSomething()
        {
            // ...some computation here

            this.handler.SomethingHappened(myContentItem);
        }
    }
}
```

*Module C*

*Handlers/BoringCustomEventHandler.cs*

```
namespace My.ModuleC.Handlers
{
    // This is the most basic eventhandler to implement
    public class BoringCustomEventHandler : IMyCustomEventHandler
    {
        public void SomethingHappened(IContent content)
        {
            // Do whatever here.

            // As you can see we handle an Event here in Module C
            // that was dispatched in Module B
            // via a service declared in Module A.
        }
    }
}
```

**Using Workflows / Activities**

Okay now it gets interesting. The combination of *Orchard.Workflows*, *Orchard.Tokens*, your custom EventHandler and your imagination 
is a very powerful way of handling all kinds of scenarios.
Modules don't even have to know each other on this level (Highly generalized statement here).

Lets have a look:

*Module A*

First we need to define a custom workflow activity.

*Activities/SomethingHappenedActivity.cs*

```
namespace My.ModuleA.Activities
{
    public class SomethingHappenedActivity : Event
    {
        // This is a neat convention for avoiding typos.
        public const string EventName = "SomethingHappened";

        // As the name says, this Activity will be able to start a workflow when triggered.
        // There are a lot of existing Activities, so I encourage you to check them out.
        public override bool CanStartWorkflow
        { 
            get { return true; }
        }

        // ... other stuff here
    }
}
```

With our custom activity in place we can finally do some workflow magic.
The possibilities here are almost endless; you can trigger other workflows, write emails, etc.

*Handlers/WorkflowMyCustomEventHandler.cs*

```
namespace My.ModuleA.Handlers
{
    // This implementation of our custom event handler will trigger workflow activities for us.
    public class WorkflowMyCustomEventHandler : IMyCustomEventHandler
    {
        private readonly IWorkflowManager workflowManager;

        public WorkflowMyCustomEventHandler(IWorkflowManager workflowManager)
        {
            this.workflowManager = workflowManager;
        }

        // Should be self-explanatory.
        // When we invoke our IMyCustomEventHandler.SomethingHappened() event,
        // this implementation will trigger our custom workflow activity.
        // Also don't forget that you can do all kinds of magic with *Orchard.Tokens*!
        public void SomethingHappened(IContent content)
        {
            this.workflowManager.TriggerEvent(
                SomethingHappenedActivity.EventName,
                content.ContentItem,
                () => new Dictionary<string,object>
                {
                    { "Content", content.ContentItem },
                    { "OtherStuff", "whatever else you want to provide here" }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I hope these examples will help you out a bit.
I've written everything from the top of my head, so I might have forgotten something.

If you have any further questions let me know in the comments and I'll update my answer or just head over to the orchard gitter channel.

Comment: Wow! It's people like you who make me proud to be a part of the Orchard community! I've been using orchard now for 2 months and this is basically the first I hear about activities.I'm going to try my best to implement it, but everything seems to make a lot more sense now. I will let you know if I have any follow up questions. Thanks again!

Comment: Great answer @Xceno, very clear and well explained, I like it